# WinEdt wrongly displaying cyrilic

Tags: miktex, winedt, cyrillic

I am trying to open a tex file with WinEdt 11 which is written in cyrilic. When i compile it no issues with the output pdf, but while i am inside the editor the cyrilic is displayed with strange symbols like this:

[image]

Could you please suggest what i am missing in the settings?

Comment: There is no way to determine text encoding for certain (autodetection is possible, but doesn't work in every case), so you probably need to specify the encoding manually when opening the file.

Comment: 1. Does your WinEdt assume that encoding is Windows-1252 code page ("ANSI") ? or, 2. The font that displays text within WinEdt : Does it have Cyrillic letters?

Comment: if latex works it must have the right encoding so will have `\usepackage[something]{inputenc}` once you have found `something` make sure your editor is set to use the same

Comment: Do you experience this problem with other text editing programs as well, or is winedt "unique" with regard to the tex file in question?

Comment: Only an experiment can help. Try it one after another:
`\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}` or
`\usepackage[cp866]{inputenc}` or
`\usepackage[koi8-r]{inputenc}` or
`\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`

Comment: which encoding does winedt report in the status line? UTF-8 or ACP?